EntraID/AzureAD - SCIM API driven provisioning to Entra - why employeeLeaveDateTime is not syncing to Entra
I use proper date format for both employeeHireDate time and employeeLeaveDateTime which is "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ" as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/how-to-lifecycle-workflow-sync-attributes
Provisioning log states that both attributes in Azure have been updated Provisioning Log, but when checking in Graph Explorer/MgGraph, employeeHireDate has value, but employeeLeaveDateTime is null Graph Explorer Output
Both attributes are synced with Direct mapping rule.
Custom schema attributes:
                "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:itixcustom:1.0:User": {
                    "employeeType": "internal",
                    "HireDateTime": "2024-07-07T01:00:00Z",
                    "LeaveDateTime": "2033-07-07T21:00:00Z"    
                }

Direct mapping:
Direct Mapping
API permissions assigned to Service Principal which is calling /bulkupload API:
API Permissions
As a workaround I can do a separate call to GRAPH API to update employeeLeaveDateTime - you need
following Graph API for this: User-LifeCycleInfo.ReadWrite.All - Allows the app to read and write the lifecycle information like employeeLeaveDateTime of users in your organization, without a signed-in user. But it doesn't really meet the expectations of /bulkupload

I resolved this.

If you use API-Driven Provisioning TO ENTRA , employeeHireDate and employeeLeaveDateTime must be in format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ" . Other formats will be treated as "skipped" action, even if datetime values change.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/how-to-lifecycle-workflow-sync-attributes
I couldn't read employeeLeaveDateTime in Graph Explorer, because I had no User-LifeCycleInfo.Read.All permission consented, User.Read.All/Directory.Read.All don't work and it shows NULL values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorial-lifecycle-workflows-set-employeeleavedatetime - after assigning User-LifeCycleInfo.Read.All to my Service Principal I could finally read employeeLeaveDateTime via MgGraph:

$User = Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId -Property EmployeeLeaveDateTime
$User.EmployeeLeaveDateTime

